# How we can count the number of records from JSON api response in Karate Framework?

Tags: rest, api, karate, web-api-testing

I want to get the count of particular key from JSON Api response in Karate Framework.

```
{

   {"user" : "a"},
   {"user" : "b"},
   {"user" : "c"}

}
```

From the above JSON i want to get the count of number of users in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs and examples carefully, you can use JavaScript directly for this:

```
* def response =
"""
[
   {"user" : "a"},
   {"user" : "b"},
   {"user" : "c"}
]
"""
* def len = response.length
* match len == 3
```

Comment: Thank you so much . Got it directly by response.length.

Comment: I am wondering how to do the same thing, but from nested json.

Comment: @djangofan ask a new question with a specific example

Comment: I figured it out separately.  Something like `def len = response[*].user.sub_el.length` .   I was just trying to point out that this answer doesn't completely answer the question.  It just answers the 1-element deep example.   I am noticing the same thing in the Karate demo examples.

Comment: @djangofan guess what. OPEN SOURCE ! :)

Comment: @PeterThomas Hopefully I can start contributing soon.   Right now, just practicing.

Comment: @djangofan that's great. sorry for ranting once in a while. in this case Ii do think if you had created a new question (and you can answer it yourself) it would help others, I see SO as additional documentation and FAQ for karate, and it seems to work well that way